# How to connect WPF Application project to Windows Game project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

I need to connect a WPF project with a Windows Game project.

I have one project done in Windows Game and another project done in WPF.

I need to open the Game1 from DemoScene project by clicking a button in WPF.

And this is method in WPF project on button click...

private void Playgame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(i don't know how to put on this);
    }
```

How can I do this?
(I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\game\Game1.exe");
```

Try the above with your path.

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx

Comment: It has an error on System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The path you give it is probably wrong. Double check the path to your .exe file

Comment: The path I gave you is just an example. You have to put the actual path to your .exe file for your game

Comment: If I wanna connect WPF project to Windows Game project in method button click, how can I do this by not using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(); because I don't have .exe file

Comment: If you are trying to start the game(process), then that is the correct way of doing it. Since the WPF application is a completely different project you will need to compile the game so you do have an exe and can start the process from the WPF application. Since they are different projects you can't just show the game like you would a form in the same project.

Comment: You can definitely access the libraries it may use or automate events, but you still need to start the process to launch the game.

Comment: @user1632018 If I want compile the game form WPF application, I must have .exe file right?

Answer (score 0):

Put your two projects in the same folder, for example, in your WPF application folder, there exists a path "game\Game1.exe". Then you can try the code below in your WPF application button click event.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.StartupPath + "game\\Game1.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks.If I wanna connect WPF project to Windows Game project in method button click, how can I do this by not using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(); because I don't have .exe file

Comment: There should exists only one Main in each solution, so if you want to combine these two projects, you may put your game startup code in your button click event. Otherwise, you can write two solutions and write a compile code to integrate two applications.